# I am getting a run time error '429'. Trying to get Excel macro to send a email

Tags: vba, outlook

```vb
Sub SendEmail()
'    SendEmail Macro
'
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = ""
    olMail.CC = ""
    olMail.Subject = " There is a change to the EMR adjustment Form that Approval"
    olMail.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: it says ActiveX component can't create object?

Comment: Do you have Outlook installed on the machine that's running the macro?

Comment: @sous2817: Outlook must be installed otherwise the line `Dim olApp As Outlook.Application` would fail. And the code seems to fail at the line `Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`. Maybe [You receive run-time error 429 when you automate Office applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications) is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You are mixing up early and late binding,*

*Late binding uses either the Visual Basic `GetObject` function or the `CreateObject` function to initialize Outlook*

*Example*

> ```
> Dim olApp as Object 
> Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
> ```

*To use early binding, you first need to set a reference to the Outlook object library, **Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library***

*Example*

> ```
> Dim olApp as Outlook.Application 
> Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
> ```